# plsql script , cant seem to build the array

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am writing a script and I don't know PLSQL well I am more MSSQL guy, I need this a script to work, I get 1 cryptic error after the next,
I need to basically create an array id numbers and add to it,

ending with selecting all cables that have an id in the array.

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
  Declare
        CableRLRevID number(10) := 5370;
         Counter Number(10) := 1;
        inp number(10) := 2;
        startId number(10) := 0;
        endId number(10) := 15;
        TYPE KableID IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
     CURSOR CableList is
select Cable_ID, Cable_GUID, Dash_Num , Fab_ID , Title, Status_ID, Notes, Cable_Items_XML, MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION,  Is_Migrated from
 ( 
select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from 
(

 select C.Cable_ID,  C.Status_ID  
from ems.Cables C where exists (select rc.CABLE_RL_REVS_CABLES_ID from ems.Cable_RL_Revs_Cables rc
where C.Cable_ID = rc.Cable_ID and rc.Cable_RL_Rev_ID = :CableRLRevID)   order by C.DASH_NUM,C.Cable_ID desc

)row_ where rownum <= :endId) where rownum_ > :startId;
END;



begin
    for KABLE in CableList
      loop

        begin
        KableID (Counter) := KABLE.Cable_ID;
          if KABLE.Status_ID = 2 or KABLE.Status_ID = 3 then
             KableID(Counter) := (KABLE.Cable_ID * -1);
            Counter := (Counter + 1);
           end if;

        end;
        Counter := (Counter + 1);
      end loop;
end;


  select * from Cables where cable_id in (select * from KableID )
```

ERROR are :

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 19, column 52: PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ;
>
> 6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>         *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>         *Action:
>         **strong text**

Comment: Please provide error as well ;)

Comment: There is unnecessary `END` before `BEGIN` (error in line 19). Additionally select statement is out of the procedure and there KebleID will be out of the scope.

Comment: If you apply some layout discipline and line up each `end` under its opening `begin` etc you'll spot the syntax error.